# Copy a field translated with django-modeltranslation to another model instance

Tags: python, django, translation, admin, django-modeltranslation

I would like to copy a translated field from a model instance var_product of class Product to another model instance var_ordered_product of class OrderedProduct.

model.py

```
class Product(OwnedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class OrderedProduct(OwnedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

translation.py

```
@register(Product) 
class ProductTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ('name', )

@register(OrderedProduct) 
class OrderedProductTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ('name', )
```

In my code

```
var_ordered_product.name = var_product.name
```

should copy the name field including all field translations.

Question: Is copying/cloning possible, without copying the language fields individually, like

```
var_ordered_product.name_en = var_product.name_en
var_ordered_product.name_fr = var_product.name_fr
```

Comment: Wether code format of translation.py is correct?

Comment: Hi Jedore, just updated the code.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your means.